# Show facebook profile pic using url in listView - Android

Tags: android, facebook, listview

i'm trying to show facebook user's profile pic using facebook graph api url and user's name.

```
String Name = jsonObjectlike.getString("name");
String UserIds = jsonObjectlike.getString("id");
URL url = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + listid + "/picture?type=small");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());

HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();
  contact.put("picid", bmp);
  contact.put("name", Name);
  contactList.add(contact);
```

and here is simpleAdapter to show in listview:

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList,R.layout.activity_listview, new String[]{"picid", "name"}, new int[]{R.id.imageView1,R.id.name});
simpleList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I successfully show name in the listView but image is not showing,

Comment: pass url of image rather than bitmap and in SimpleAdapter use Glide to show image.

Comment: Can you please show the example...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed myself by creating custom listView adapter that contains decoded image url and text. It works perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
String Name = jsonObjectlike.getString("name");
String UserIds = jsonObjectlike.getString("id");
URL url = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + listid + "/picture?type=small");

HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();
//contact.put("picid", bmp);<- use Image URL not bitmap
contact.put("picid", url);
contact.put("name", Name);
contactList.add(contact);
```

And in your SimpleAdapter handle is picid and show in Imageview with Glide library.

Comment: contact.put("picid", url); this line required string not Target<GlideDrawable>

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView user_picture;
 userpicture=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.userpicture);
 URL img_value = null;
 img_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?type=large");
 Bitmap mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
 userpicture.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);
```